# Php redirection Involving javascript check

Tags: javascript, php

I am using some html code and javascript code in php. ALL THE CODE BOTH HTML AND JAVASCRIPT IS ALREAY IN ECHO.The html code is like this:

```
<div id="ShippingInfo">
   <label>Available Quantity &nbsp;'.$value.' Meters</label><br><br>
   <label>Want to Buy  &nbsp; </label>
   <input id= "userDemand" type="number"  size="20" name="UserDemand" value="" aria-describedby="name-format"   placeholder="Enter Integers Only" pattern="\d*"  >&nbsp; <label ><font size="3">meters</font></label>        <br><br>
   <label>Cost&nbsp; </label><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="validateMyForm()">
</div>
```

On button onclick I am calling a javascript method like this:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function validateMyForm() 
{ 
    if ((document.getElementById('userDemand').value )<='".$value."')
    { 
        document.location = 'AB17.php?cat='".$pCat."'&productType='".$pName."'&page='".$page."';
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }   
}
</script>
```

All the code is ecohing so there is no issue with quotes.And the problem is it is not working.When I click on the button nothing happens .Please help !

Answer (score 0):

You can not use PHP variables in **JS** just like this-

```
cat='".$pCat."'
```

Use it like this instead-

```
...cat='<?php echo $pCat;'&....
```

Similarly in **HTML**-

```
.....Quantity &nbsp; <?php echo $value; ?> Meters....
```

Comment: the whole script is already in echo.This html and javascript code is written inside php , so it is in echo already .I am already echoing the code .

Comment: That's not really a goo d way, I mean chances of erros are more change the code applying these changes and then try

Answer (score 0):

If you use server variable or php variable you need to use `<?php` open and close php tagge `?>`

```
   function validateMyForm() 
   { 
        if ((document.getElementById('userDemand').value )<=<?php echo $value; ?>)
        { 
        document.location = 'AB17.php?cat=<?php echo $pCat; ?>&productType=<?php echo $pName; ?>&page=<?php echo $page; ?>;
                  return true;

        }
                else
                {
            return false;
                }   
    }
    </script>
```

in html

```
   <label>Available Quantity &nbsp; <?php $value ?> Meters</label><br><br>
```